# PHP: Validate string containing numbers, separated by hyphen (possible by preg_match)?

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I’m trying to validate a string which contains numbers where each four numbers are separated by a hyphen, for example 1111-2222-3333-4444

I’m trying to do some kind of validating so I can guarantee that this format is being used (with 16 digits, three hyphens and nothing else). I’ve this preg_match where it checks for digits only but I need to accept hyphens and this format.

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', $validatenumbers)
```

I’ve tried to do it with regex but unfortunately it isn’t my strongest side so I haven’t been able to correctly validate the numbers.

It is important that it is in PHP and not Javascript because of the ability to “turn off” javascript in a browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]{4}-){3}[0-9]{4}$/", $input);
```

`([0-9]{4}-){3}` Matches exactly 3 groups of 4 digits followed by a hyphen. That is terminated by another group `[0-9]{4}` (4 digits without a hyphen).

Comment: +1 but `([0-9]{3}-){3}` matches 3 digits, not 4. **edit** and you could write `\d` instead of `[0-9]` but that's personal preference I guess

Comment: @Rudie whoa thanks, a typo and then duplicated by copy / paste

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}$/',$numbers);
```

i think that should work.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a credit card number. If that's the case, you should use a [`Luhn checksum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) instead of a simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(preg_match('#^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$#',$string){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require to match that exact format the pattern would be `'~^\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$~'`, or you can write it more generally like this: `'/^(\d+-)*\d+$/'` (this would match 11, 11-11111... and so on),